# App that is not showing on projector

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to create an app on .NET that will be used when connected with projector/external PC but will be shown only on main screen?

Thanks.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with it, but i want to built in on .NET!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Powerpoint has the functionality of showing notes just on the primary display. But this is only possible when the desktop gets extended and not mirrored to the beamer.

So you shold have to extend the desktop to the beamer and then place the App window on the main screen manually.

`System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens` gives you access to monitor information in C#. The PrimaryScreen Property tells you, which screen is the main Screen. You may move the window from one screen to another by respecting the screen widths.